# How to revert an object to previous values when back pressed?

Tags: android, data-binding

Firstly I'm sorry for my poor English. I am using databinding in my project.
 For example; I send a model/pojo/entity class using Parcelable from a fragment to another fragment.
So, between two fragment... When I make to change in the model/pojo/entity class, and clicked back button the changes still seem.
But I want to save the changes when I clicked submit button. 
If any user don't click submit button, the changes should be not be saved in the model class.

Comment: You can set the default value to the variables in your pojo class when you want changes to be cancel

Comment: I have found a method. What do you think that if I clone pojo class, is that good method?

Answer (score 1):

Just clone the object and make changes to the clone and then replace the original with clone on submit button.